# How import async into client side nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, client, async.js

Suppose to have a client file `home.js`

```
"use strict";

(function() {
//Supose to have an array
var array_user=.....
for(var i=0;i<array_user.length;i++){ // change with asyn.each whenre async=require('async'
    call_async_function(array_user[i].....);

}

});

}());
```

The proble is that the file is in the client side and I need to delete this `for()` and put an syncronized element like `async.each`. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with something like this:

```
async function test() {
  const array_user = .....

  for (let my_val of array_user) {
    await array_user[my_val];
  }
};

test()
```